# Free JSP plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I was looking out for a free plugin for developing/debugging JSP pages in eclipse.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BEA seems to have a free one [BEA JSP plugin](http://commerce.bea.com/products/workshop/workshop_prod_fam.jsp) - not used it, so not sure how good it is.

Oracle now owns BEA, and they have this [plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/workshop/overview/index.html) which might do a similar job.

Comment: Hey, now the link is broken. Anyone who knows its new location?

Answer (score 5):

The [Eclipse Web Tools Platform Project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:Eclipse_Web_Tools_Platform_Project) includes a JSP debugger. I have only ever needed to use it with Tomcat so I cannot say how well it works with other servlet containers.

Comment: This is by default included in "Eclipse for Java EE developers" which you actually should have downloaded instead of "Eclipse for Java developers".

Answer (score 4):

The former BEA Workshop is now [Oracle Workshop](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/ias/bea_main.html#devtools). It is the best JSP editor with WYSIWYG support and it is free. It is not specific to WebLogic. Basic JSP editing is server neutral anyway. However, it supports launching and debugging on many servers.

You can read my [blog post](http://blog.zvikico.com/2008/08/the-best-jspstrutsjsf-development-tool-is-now-free.html) about it.

Comment: It seems Oracle Workshop is now Oracle Workshop for WebLogic. Hard to tell how server-agnostic it could be. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/workshop/overview/index.html